# Can normal distribution prob density be greater than 1?... based on python code checkup

Tags: python, statistics, probability

I have a question: 
Given mean and variance I want to calculate the probability of a sample using a normal distribution as probability basis. 
The numbers are:

```
mean = -0.546369
var = 0.006443
curr_sample = -0.466102

prob = 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*var))*np.exp( -( ((curr_sample - mean)**2)/(2*var) ) )
```

I get a probability which is larger than 1! I get prob = 3.014558...

What is causing this? The fact that the variance is too small messes something up? It's a totally legal input to the formula and should give something small not greater than 1! Any suggestions?

Comment: I get `0.12203763789602547` running your example...

Comment: He is missing the 1 over part in front!

Comment: Thanks johnsharpe - I restarted the Eclipse (Luna) and it still gives 3.014!!! How???? I don't even know what to check - no errors in debug, nothing! :-(

Comment: You missed a 1 over in front of the formula

Comment: The example that I gave had 1/ and now someone (moderators?) have changed it..

Comment: Nobody has edited your question; if they had, we would be able to see it.

Comment: I did now edit, but it is under review

Comment: My fault then - sorry about that. In any case, the 3.014 appears when you run the corrected 1/... formula. Can you please try this one?

Comment: If I add `1. / ` back in I do now get `3.014...`

Comment: You probably did have a typo in your expression. However, you are nonetheless making a category error: the formula is a _probability density_, not a _probability_. A density *can* be greater than one. What exactly are you trying to figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you give is a *probability density*, not a *probability*. The density formula is such that when you *integrate* it between two values of `x`, you get the probability of being in that interval. However, this means that the probability of getting any particular sample is, in fact, 0 (it's the density times the infinitesimally small `dx`).

So what are you actually trying to calculate? You probably want something like the probability of getting *your value or larger*, the so-called tail probability, which is often used in statistics (it so happens that this is given by the [error function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.erf) when you're talking about a normal distribution, although you need to be careful of exactly how it's defined).

Answer (score 5):

Ok, what you compute is not a probability, but a probability density (which may be larger than one). In order to get 1 you have to integrate over the normal distribution like so:

```
import numpy as np
mean = -0.546369
var = 0.006443
curr_sample = np.linspace(-10,10,10000)

prob = np.sum( 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*var))*np.exp( -( ((curr_sample - mean)**2)/(2*var) ) ) * (curr_sample[1]-curr_sample[0]) )
print prob
```

witch results in

```
0.99999999999961509
```

Comment: This is true, but it just means that the OP doesn't know what he's trying to calculate...

Comment: Yes, I am just telling him what to do to get 1. It is sometimes easier to see that if you also see that the integrated probability is in fact one!

Comment: You are wrong about `var`! The variance is sigma**2 which is correct in the OP's formula (at least as it is now).

Comment: I am an idiot - forgot that the peak value is 1/sqrt(2*pi*var) and not less than 1 as with discrete variables with which I worked recently. I am not trying to get 1, merely to have a ML/MAP-like approximation of something and was checking the results. This settled it. Thanks for the answers, correction of the typo in the original question, correction of the slight abuse of notations (D rather than PDF) and other useful extremely building comments.

Answer (score 1):

When considering the bell-shaped probability distribution function (PDF) of given mean and variance, the peak value of the curve (height of mode) is 1/sqrt(2*pi*var). It is 1 for standard normal distribution (mean 0 and var 1). Hence when trying to calculate a specific value of a general normal distribution pdf, values larger than 1 are possible.